# Why are my questions about what experiences lead to becoming a CEO always being downvoted/deleted?

Tags: discussion

Title says it all... I'm a bit frustrated now.

I am looking for guidance on career development. Why is there a tag for career development if a valid question on career development is somewhat "taboo" here?

I don't really know whether I understand.

I am confused.

Please help!!!

Comment: I'll spell it out for you. Somebody has already pointed out to you the FAQ. I think you missed this point *"How do I learn to be a..." / "How do I perform the job of a ..."

    Questions should be about problems you are encountering or have encountered in the workplace, and not the learning/applying of specific job functions.*

Comment: Also you should never ask this kind of meta question on Workplace (why are your questions being downvoted). On StackExchange, each subsite has a sister site called Meta-XXX (in this case Meta-Workplace) which covers topics about the Workplace site.

Comment: Make an appointment with a career counselor and drive them nuts. I can almost guarantee you that if you asked similar questions at a student career fair, you won't even get an entry level position. It takes several people to say "yes" but it takes only one to say "no" - Look at your downvotes and take a hint. As for our "career" tag, read the questions that are thus tagged: almost all of them are specific, focused and thus answerable. And a big thank you to our readers for asking questions that are specific, focused and thus answerable.

Comment: Well... what can be worse than feeling ignored and downvoted/deleted without explanation?

Comment: As far as what experienced lead to becoming a CEO.. I'm a CEO. But I'm also 19 and don't make any money with my business yet. *How you you become a CEO?*  -- **Step 1:** Take initiative. **Step 2.** Practice intelligent reasoning and informed decision making. **Step 3.** Make mistakes. *Learn from them.*

Comment: @AspiringCEO I've asked a lot of bad questions on SE. My SO account has over a hundred questions, and looking back, I'd say that each one (while not being the best) got a little bit better and more helpful to a wider audience. Instead of creating a post to try and make people feel sorry for you, try posting on Meta about a specific question when you don't understand why it is not good.

Answer (score 8):

It's not that a question about improving one's career is off-topic. Instead, the question you're asking is too broad for our site's Q&A format. As a Stack Exchange site, we're not a discussion forum, and the questions we've chosen to field on our site are those that are self-contained, provide plenty of detail about a real, actual problem you're facing, and that can be answered in a few paragraphs or more, without extended discussion or debate.

A question about how to become a CEO is first and foremost way too broad, something that entire books have been written about, and something that has already been asked and answered elsewhere on the Internet.

Check out our site's [list of topics in the Help Center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for more details.

With that said, if your questions are put on hold, the idea is that you would edit that post and improve it. Simply copy-pasting closed or on-hold questions into new posts simply creates a lot of noise on our site, and dilutes our community's efforts to help edit and improve them for release back into the pool.

I see you have a couple accounts, I'd suggest registering your account so you don't keep losing it. This will help make it easier for you to edit and improve your post, and also, as you gain reputation, that will also accumulate in one place. Hope this helps!

Comment: Aside from being too broad it is literally a quesiton asking for both what skills to learn and what jobs to takes... both of which are off topic on their own this is kind of uber off-topic